# Wifi Repeater for All Wifi Signals or else Secure Network without Credentials?

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater, wireless-extender

Are there any wifi repeaters that can repeat all signals it finds? Maybe even if just on a single channel? Or at the very least can it repeat an SSID without knowing its credentials? I have wifi cameras on a closed network that even I can't log in to but would like to repeat their signals.